# Can BoringCrypto be used only for Linux (linux_amd64 and linux_arm64)?

Tags: go, cgo, fips

*Context*: there's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638176/how-can-i-check-whether-my-golang-app-uses-boringcrypto-instead-of-the-native-go) that says that in order to make an app FIPS compliant one should use BoringCrypto which is wrapper around BoringSSL.

But I had some issues properly compiling with it on MacOS (using `GOEXPERIMENT=boringcrypto`), so eventually I got to golang [sources](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/crypto/internal/boring/syso).

Looks like there are syso files only for `linux_amd64` and `linux_arm64`, does it mean that BoringCrypto can be used only for Linux? Does anybody have any context around it?

Comment: Linux is the only supported platform according to https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4f4a9c7fff0b96d596c65f7997ab646b3ac42517/src/crypto/boring/boring_test.go#L16.